# after building kubernetes using docker how to startup a local cluster from these docker images?

Tags: kubernetes

According to [docs on building kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/685e421b89d8c67f680b15e5b4894263c8017da5/build/README.md) it says you can run `build/run.sh make` to build `kubernetes`.

After you build it locally with `docker`, how do you start a local cluster from this build? In order to experiment the just recently `kubernetes` build you have built locally..